# Reload page in PHP after form submission

Tags: javascript, php

I have one page where i can Approve or Delete comments which user submitted on my blog (I built the blog without Wordpress with PHP and MySQL) Now everything is working fine and i just need help with one question.
 I'm deleting and approving comments from one page means i have separate queries but both are on same page and i want to auto-refresh page only once after submitting of form, below is code which i has.
 For approving comment -

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_POST['approve_cmt'])) {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $sql = "UPDATE `blog_comments` SET `status` = '1' WHERE comment_id = '$id'";
      $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
       if ($res == 1) {
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Comment approved!') window.location.reload(); </script>";
         } else {
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Failed to approve comment') window.location.reload(); </script>";
       }
      } 
;?>
```

for deleting comment

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete_cmt'])) {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $sql = "DELETE FROM `blog_comments` WHERE `comment_id` = '$id'";
      $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
       if ($res == 1) {
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('comment deleted') window.location.reload(); </script>";
         } else {
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('unable to delete comment') window.location.reload(); </script>";
         }
     }

    ;?>
```

Comment: You want to delete and confirm comments at the same time by just one click?

Comment: What's with the `;` before the closing PHP-tags?

Comment: @PatrickMlr Not at all, I have one form with two buttons and one query either delete or approve will happen at once depending upon which button clicked, I tested the functionality of codes and it's working fine but page is not reloading after showing alert as above are codes.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that does not matter, it's `<?php ;?>`

Comment: **1.** Don't use the deprecated mysql_*-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. **2.** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which works with MySQLi and PDO. --- This matters, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect('Location: the_same_page_name');